# Query to check groups of unique values from the current data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get from the current data in my database, the columns that have unique values ​​and the group of columns with unique values.

For example, for columns that have unique values ​​I have this query:

```sql
SELECT t.columnToCheck
FROM table t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table d WHERE d.t.columnToCheck = t.t.columnToCheck and d.id <> t.id)
```

What I have done has been to check if there is data for each column of the table, and the one that does not have results is the one that I consider as unique. This works for me and is ok.

What I want now is to check if there are groups of columns with unique values. For example, if I do a SELECT from column 1, column 2, and column 3 with the values ​​1x, 2x, and 3x in the WHERE does not repeat, I would consider it a unique column group.

For example:
[image]

In this case, with the data that exists, we can say that the combination between name and shortname would be unique since it is not repeated in any other column. However, the name and email combination is not unique because it is repeated. What I want is to get all the unique combinations from among all the columns.

How could I check all these column combinations to check it in a quick and easy way?

I have tried to manually perform some combinations of column groups but its impossible to manually test all combinations of columns.

Comment: It helps if you provide a table of data to demonstrate the scenarios, that way we can provide a targeted answer. Hypotheticals don't really mix with SQL

Comment: @ChrisSchaller just edited adding an example, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 basic mechanisms to check for duplicates, `WHERE NOT EXISTS` as you have found:

```
SELECT Id, column1, column2, column3 
FROM <table> src 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM <table> chk 
    WHERE src.Id <> chk.Id 
      AND src.column1 = chk.column1 
      AND src.column2 = chk.column2 
      AND src.column3 = chk.column3 
)
```

Or if you do not need the specific rows, but you just want to know the duplicate values, or that there are duplicates, then you can use `GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as [count], column1, column2, column3
FROM <table> src 
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

*It is not strictly necessary to return the `COUNT(*)` but it can be helpful analysis if you suspect there will be more than a count of 2.*